# How to handle nested parentheses with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I came up with a regex string that parses the given text into 3 categories:

- in parentheses
- in brackets
- neither.

Like this:

```
\[.+?\]|\(.+?\)|[\w+ ?]+
```

My intention is to use the outermost operator only. So, given `a(b[c]d)e`, the split is going to be:

```
a || (b[c]d) || e
```

It works fine given parentheses inside brackets, or brackets inside parentheses, but breaks down when there are brackets inside brackets and parentheses inside parentheses. For example, `a[b[c]d]e` is split as

```
a || [b[c] || d || ] || e.
```

Is there any way to handle this using regex alone, not resorting to using code to count number of open/closed parentheses? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you create your own parser?

Comment: Which language are you using for this? Regular expressions can (in theory) not parse nested structures. If you are using .NET or Perl/PCRE, you might be lucky though, because they have some advanced features that can.

Comment: The language of nested parentheses is not regular. Hence 'regular' expressions (in the mathematical sense of the term) are not up to the job. period.

Comment: Rohit - I am trying to create a parser for a context free grammar (JSGF), for which I need to split the text into the three categories. Then my script goes through them recursively one nested level at a time. 

M, I am using python. Which I guess puts me in the unfortunate category.

Comment: @MinasAbovyan just split your string into the matches of something like `[[\]()]|[^[\]()]+` (the brackets in question and anything else). then walk the matches, incrementing the relevant depth counters when encountering each bracket type.

Comment: Yes, that is probably what I will end up doing. I was hoping for an easier way out though :) Thanks!

Comment: Is it fair to assume that there should never be empty pairs of brackets or parenthesis (or that if they exist, they should be discarded)? Example: `a()b` would be invalid, and should match as `a || b`

Comment: Joe, given my input, no, there will never be such a case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard<sup>1</sup> regular expressions are not sophisticated enough to match nested structures like that. The best way to approach this is probably to traverse the string and keep track of opening / closing bracket pairs.

---

<sup>1</sup> I said *standard*, but not all regular expression engines are indeed standard. You might be able to this with Perl, for instance, by using recursive regular expressions. For example:

```
$str = "[hello [world]] abc [123] [xyz jkl]";

my @matches = $str =~ /[^\[\]\s]+ | \[ (?: (?R) | [^\[\]]+ )+ \] /gx;

foreach (@matches) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

```
[hello [world]]
abc
[123]
[xyz jkl]
```

---

**EDIT:** I see you're using Python; check out [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Well, once you abandon the idea that parsing nested expressions should work at unlimited depth, one can use regular expressions just fine by specifying a maximum depth in advance.  Here is how:

```
def nested_matcher (n):
    # poor man's matched paren scanning, gives up after n+1 levels.
    # Matches any string with balanced parens or brackets inside; add
    # the outer parens yourself if needed.  Nongreedy.  Does not
    # distinguish parens and brackets as that would cause the
    # expression to grow exponentially rather than linearly in size.
    return "[^][()]*?(?:[([]"*n+"[^][()]*?"+"[])][^][()]*?)*?"*n

import re

p = re.compile('[^][()]+|[([]' + nested_matcher(10) + '[])]')
print p.findall('a(b[c]d)e')
print p.findall('a[b[c]d]e')
print p.findall('[hello [world]] abc [123] [xyz jkl]')
```

This will output

```
['a', '(b[c]d)', 'e']
['a', '[b[c]d]', 'e']
['[hello [world]]', ' abc ', '[123]', ' ', '[xyz jkl]']
```

Comment: This search actually deleted all of my input EXCEPT for parentheses themsel\/es